# Retrieving Head of an Option[List[...]]

Tags: scala

Given a `Some(List("hello"))` and wanting to get `"hello"`, I observed the following behavior.

```
scala> val list = Some(List("hello"))
list: Some[List[String]] = Some(List(hello))

scala> list.head.head
res3: String = hello
```

Then, I checked, the [Scaladocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) and saw that `head` will `Select the first element of this iterable collection.` It also points out that an exception will be thrown if the collection is empty.

Is this retrieval of the first element of a Option[List] considered idiomatic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not *not* idiomatic, but I would be inclined to prefer:

```
scala> val hd = list.flatMap(_.headOption)
hd: Option[String] = Some(hello)
```

And keep working with an Option value.

Answer (score 4):

The answer really depends on what you want to do next with the value. For instance, you could use what @Shadowlands proposed and keep working the `Option` using `map` and `flatMap`. Another thing you could do is use pattern matching:

```
list match {
  case Some(head :: tail) => soSomethingWith(head)
  case Some(Nil) => dealWithEmptyList
  case None => dealWithNone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're expression is not idiomatic. `Some` is a way of Scala dealing with the possibility of a null value. One can explain the concept of a `Some` as a list that only has a head and no tail, but only as a metaphor not as idiomatic usage. What you are really expressing is a nested list:

```
val list: List[List[String]] = List(List("hello"))
```

However, if you had 100% certainty that `list` has a value, which is non-empty list, then I would do this:

```
list match { case Some(xs) => xs.head }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a for-comprehension to get at the head option if you were so inclined.  I would probably prefer @Shadowlands answer because it's a bit more succinct, but this would work as well:

```
val headOpt = 
  for{
    list <- listOpt
    head <- list.headOption
  } yield head
```